# VBA to print worksheet and delete selected row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a template that users fill out to auto populate into legal documents that needs to be printed. Once the first "unit's" documents have been printed the user deletes that row bringing up the next unit to auto populate the necessary forms and so on. Basically I am trying to eliminate the manual step of printing and deleting rows so I am wondering how to create a macro to print the forms and once printed delete the row and move to the next unit looping until there are no more units. Any sort of direction would be helpful!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To get positive attention on your question, the best way is to write out something, as much as you can, to help us start out. A vague question with no starting point is usually not well received. Have you started to look into anything, or done any research beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some vague direction...
It's best to start by recording a macro and seeing what is written to the module in the VBA editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>). There will be a lot of extra fluff that isn't required, and there won't be any sort of loop. You should be able to trim it down and add a loop to do what you want. It would probably look something like this:

```
Sub PrintAllOfMyStuff()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheetOfRows").Range("A1").Select

    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheetToPrint").PrintOut
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete (xlUp)
    Loop

End Sub
```